# Orthogonal principal component of submatrix

Tags: pca, linear-model

Consider a data matrix $M_{n ~ x ~Features}$ and its top two principal components ($PC_1$ and $PC_2$). For any of submatrix $S_{n ~x ~F}$, where $F \subset Features$ (i.e. S contains all samples but a subset of Features), how to find principal components of S that are also orthogonal to $PC_1$ and $PC_2$?

A heuristic approach might be to find principal components of $S - W_1 * PC_1 - W_2 *PC_2  $, where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are linear regression coefficient. Is this correct or any other better/principled approach?

Comment: Please explain what sense of "independence" you are using: is this the probabilistic meaning, where the matrix is random, or perhaps do you mean "linearly independent"?  And in that case, please explain how a PC of a *submatrix* can reasonably be compared to a PC of the main matrix.  (This will depend on what you mean by "submatrix.")

Comment: @whuber Yes, I meant linearly independent (i.e. orthogonal). Also for the sake of simplicity lets assume M is normally distributed. I also clarified the submatrix S contains all samples but only a subset of features.

Comment: Thank you.  The answer to your modified question is "yes."